# Getting 200 OK abd 400 bad request on the same request from Google Drive REST API

Tags: rest, http, google-drive-api

My Google Drive app checks on start if its settings files(the files are all on Drive) has changed. Thus on every start sends a files.list request to the Google Drive API to get the files metadata. The app has been used for more then 4 months with no suspicious beahaviour from this request. But the last few days a strange thing is happening. The problem is that from time to time(every 1 out of 10-20 starts) the request gets this response

```
 {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
```

In all other cases the request gets an adequate response(200 OK mostly :)).
This is very strange because every time the request is the same and the query string( the q parameter) of course is the same i.e.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?corpus=DEFAULT&q=(title%3D'%5BClosed+Captions%5D.profile'+or+title%3D'Profiles'+or+title%3D'%5BGeneral%5D.profile'+or+title%3D'%5BTeletext%5D.profile'+or+title%3D'ezt5RoamingSettings.ini'+or+title%3D'ezt5ProjectSettings.ini'+or+title%3D'Project+Templates'+or+title%3D'ezt5IOPresets.ini'+or+title%3D'dicAutoCorrect.xml'+or+title%3D'dicShortForms.xml'+or+title%3D'dicDictionaries.xml')+and+trashed%3Dfalse&fields=items(fileSize%2C+id%2C+title%2C+modifiedDate%2C+md5Checksum%2C+parents(id%2C+isRoot))&key={MY_API_KEY}
```

Any ideas why is this happening will be much appreciated...

Comment: Wild guess would be its a parsing issue with the ''s and the %'s. or a server hiccup.  I would try and catch the error and just resend it.

Comment: Yes the solution seems obvious. What really bothers me here is What is the problem :)

Comment: its probably something as simple as a connection issue.  I don't think its anything you can control.